# Apache: mod_proxy_balancer and set keepalive timeout

Tags: apache, timeout, mod-proxy-balancer

we are using `apache 2.4.10` on a `SLES 10` system and don't know how to set a `keep-alive-time` in the modul mod_proxy_balancer. We would like to configure a keepalive time of 10 minutes. We made several tests with timeouts but the global apache parameter `KeepAliveTimeout` and the `OS-parameter` TCP Keepalive Timeout (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time`) have no effect.

Is there a parameter for this Proxy-Balancer timeout or do you know another way to configure a keepalive time of 10 minutes?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what timeout you expect to be 10 minutes? proxy_balancer and keepalive don't really make sense together.

Comment: The module mod_jk has the parameter socket_keepalive=true. This flag will tell the Operating System to send KEEP_ALIVE messages on inactive connections, and thus prevent the firewall to cut inactive connections.
Do you know how I can configure this for the proxy_balancer?

Comment: @AndreBaumann did you ever find out how to configure this? We've tried https://serverfault.com/questions/185894/proxy-error-502-reason-error-reading-from-remote-server-with-apache-2-2-3-de but that did not work